# XSLT- Can not extract child nodes of a given node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML File and want to extract some portion of this XML File. I tried different xslts but I did not work. I couldn't understand where I made a mistake.

**Sample File**

```
   <GetDataResponse xmlns="http://test">
         <GetDataResult>
            <Classification>TEST</Classification>
            <data>
               <ItemList xmlns="">
                  <Item>
                     <CommonMetadata>
                        <InfoCoreId>6719d364-7145-4f60-b5c2-07c38a29cce5</InfoCoreId>
                        <FirstReceivedTimestamp>2020-03-31T12:29:51.977Z</FirstReceivedTimestamp>
                        <LastUpdatedTimestamp>2020-03-31T12:29:51.977Z</LastUpdatedTimestamp>
                        <CacheExpiresOnTimestamp>2020-04-28T12:29:51.977Z</CacheExpiresOnTimestamp>
                        <IsDeleted>False</IsDeleted>
                        <ADSName>Test</ADSName>
                        <ADSURI/>
                        <ADSInfoCoreId>885bc303-13b2-48e2-8186-8d60cb0ceecf</ADSInfoCoreId>
                        <IngestionName>Test</IngestionName>
                        <IngestionId>bd0c753e-5262-48cd-b946-7f3a1220ac31</IngestionId>
                        <Description>Test</Description>
                        <SourceAssignedId/>
                        <SourceChecksum/>
                        <Author/>
                        <Geography>
                           <KMLRepresentation>
                              <kml:kml xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
                                 <kml:Placemark>
                                    <kml:description>TEST</kml:description>
                                    <kml:Point>
                                       <kml:coordinates>111111,22222</kml:coordinates>
                                    </kml:Point>
                                 </kml:Placemark>
                              </kml:kml>
                           </KMLRepresentation>
                        </Geography>
                        <BSO/>
                        <ModeOfOperation>Live</ModeOfOperation>
                     </CommonMetadata>
                  </Item>
               </ItemList>
            </data>
            <xsltOutputFormat/>
         </GetDataResult>
      </GetDataResponse>
```

I want to get the all the nodes and their values under the "data" element node like below;

**Expected File**

```
              <ItemList xmlns="">
                  <Item>
                     <CommonMetadata>
                        <InfoCoreId>6719d364-7145-4f60-b5c2-07c38a29cce5</InfoCoreId>
                        <FirstReceivedTimestamp>2020-03-31T12:29:51.977Z</FirstReceivedTimestamp>
                        <LastUpdatedTimestamp>2020-03-31T12:29:51.977Z</LastUpdatedTimestamp>
                        <CacheExpiresOnTimestamp>2020-04-28T12:29:51.977Z</CacheExpiresOnTimestamp>
                        <IsDeleted>False</IsDeleted>
                        <ADSName>Test</ADSName>
                        <ADSURI/>
                        <ADSInfoCoreId>885bc303-13b2-48e2-8186-8d60cb0ceecf</ADSInfoCoreId>
                        <IngestionName>Test</IngestionName>
                        <IngestionId>bd0c753e-5262-48cd-b946-7f3a1220ac31</IngestionId>
                        <Description>Test</Description>
                        <SourceAssignedId/>
                        <SourceChecksum/>
                        <Author/>
                        <Geography>
                           <KMLRepresentation>
                              <kml:kml xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
                                 <kml:Placemark>
                                    <kml:description>TEST</kml:description>
                                    <kml:Point>
                                       <kml:coordinates>111111,22222</kml:coordinates>
                                    </kml:Point>
                                 </kml:Placemark>
                              </kml:kml>
                           </KMLRepresentation>
                        </Geography>
                        <BSO/>
                        <ModeOfOperation>Live</ModeOfOperation>
                     </CommonMetadata>
                  </Item>
               </ItemList>
```

**Applied XSLT-1**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="GetDataResponse/GetDataResult/data">

   <xsl:value-of select="."/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied XSLT-2**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="GetDataResponse/GetDataResult/data">

    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But none of these work for me. What is the problem with my xslt?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The expected result you show is confusing. There should be no need for a `xmlns=""` "undeclaration" when there is no preceding namespace declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should review the namespaces used in your input file.

Here's a solution that does what you want.
Note that you can't ignore the namespaces, you have to take it into account when precessing the nodes.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tst="http://test">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tst:GetDataResponse/tst:GetDataResult/tst:data"/>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyS

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you for the reply. I do not want <data> element in my result file. What can I do for that ?

Comment: Indeed, you can't ignore the namespaces. This solution produces an XML where all nodes are in the `"http://test"` namespace. My impression is that OP wants a result that is in no-namespace.

Comment: @mhendek You can change the select path select="tst:GetDataResponse/tst:GetDataResult/tst:data" to whatever you want in your output file. Go one level down if you don't want the <data> node.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes possibly, though it's not clear from the question how the namespace should be treated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without namespaces :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//ItemList"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDiMBU

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//ItemList"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Although personally I would prefer a more explicit path:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="*/*/*/ItemList"/>
```